# Using .map instead of For-loop to unwrapping an array inside of an array Swift?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, for-loop

I am trying to switch my for-loop out with .map but I am stuck with a problem unwrapping an array inside of an array.

My code looks like this. (*commodityData* contains the data I need in JSON)

```
    var symbols: [CropCategoryName] = []

    for data in commodityData {

        let name = data.commodity.crop.name
        let exchange = data.commodity.exchange
                
            for futureData in data.futures {
                    
                let monthName = futureData.monthName
                let year = futureData.year
                    
                let crop = CropCategoryName.init(identifier: futureData.symbol, display: String(name) + " (" + String(exchange) + ") " + String(monthName) + " " + String(year))
                    crop.symbol = futureData.symbol
                    
                symbols.append(crop)
                }
```

I've tried the following but can't seem to unwrap the *let futuree*[[image: array inside of array, futuree]] to get the .monthName and .year data without using a for-loop inside a for-loop after the clousure.

```
let name1 = commodityData.map({$0.commodity.crop.name})
let exchange1 = commodityData.map({$0.commodity.exchange})
            
let futuree = commodityData.map({ (future) -> [Future] in
                
    return future.futures })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you want each `data` in `commodityData` to map to *multiple* `CropCategoryName` - one `CropCategoryName` for each future the data has. This is a use case of [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2905332-flatmap):

```
let symbols = commodityData.flatMap { data -> [CropCategoryName] in
    // this closure maps each commodity data to a bunch of crop category names
    let name = data.commodity.crop.name
    let exchange = data.commodity.exchange

    return data.futures.map { futureData -> CropCategoryName in
        // this closure maps each future to a crop category name
        let monthName = futureData.monthName
        let year = futureData.year

        // I would recommend extracting this to a separate function
        let crop = CropCategoryName.init(identifier: futureData.symbol, display: String(name) + " (" + String(exchange) + ") " + String(monthName) + " " + String(year))
        crop.symbol = futureData.symbol
        return crop
    }
}
```